# Pyinstaller doesn't include packages

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert a python file to an executable file using pyinstaller. I have 2 modules I need to import: kivy and [KahootPY](https://pypi.org/project/KahootPY/).

The command I used:

`pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --hidden-import KahootPY --icon "icon.ico" --add-data "Default.ttf;." --add-data "kahoot.kv;."  "Bot.py"`

For some reason it says `unknown module: KahootPY`

Comment: That’s probably because the import name of KahootPY is `kahoot`, as used in your code.

Comment: I already tried that, It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I just added `--additional-hooks-dir "C:/Path/To/Package/Files"`, and remove `--hidden-import`.